# searching based on a search term and a location

Tags: search, geolocation, search-engine

We want to build a search engine based on a search term and a location. Something like Skill Pages, which prompts for a skill you are looking for and the location (e.g. http://www.skillpages.com/i/Search/Browse?Location=new+york&SearchTerm=designer&SearchType=SKILLS).

This is an incereasing common way of searching and I've been wondering how it is achieved.

Do these sites use google api to return a longitude and latitude of the location the user has entered, then decide on a radius, say 50km, and search skills within that radius (still on Skill Pages example)?

With this method, how is the radius decided on? For example, if a user chooses "London", the radius would be much smaller than if a user chooses "UK"...

What's the best method to achieve this form of search?

Answer (score 0):

check out how google places work. it must be very similar that you want.